# Exception during run ready code

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-storm

When I imported written code using Eclipse and run it as java application, I get an Exception during run ready code

This is the error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setBolt(Ljava/lang/String;Lbacktype/storm/    topology/IBasicBolt;Ljava/lang/Integer;)Lbacktype/storm/topology/BoltDeclarer; 
at TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:18)
```

Code is

```
import spouts.WordReader; 
import backtype.storm.Config; 
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder; 
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields; 
import bolts.WordCounter; import bolts.WordNormalizer;

public class TopologyMain { public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException { 
  //Topology definition 
  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder(); 
  builder.setSpout("word-reader",new WordReader());
  builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer()).shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
  builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),1).fieldsGrouping("word- normalizer", new Fields("word"));

  //Configuration 
  Config conf = new Config();
  conf.put("wordsFile",  args[0]);  onf.setDebug(false);

  //Topology run 
  conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);

  LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster(); 
  cluster.submitTopology("Getting-Started-Toplogie", conf,  builder.createTopology());

  Thread.sleep(1000); cluster.shutdown(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the setBolt method accept the parameters you're passing?

Comment: Did you recompile the code after importing ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've modified your `TopologyBuilder` class or JAR having that class. Because that kind of error implies that your compile-time and run-time versions of classes are not the same, i.e. the .class has been somehow modified after you compiled your program. Particularly, the program was compiled with `setBolt()` method, and after that, the method was removed, renamed or modified within .class

Answer (score 0):

The program and method arguments that you are passing as `builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter(),1).fields...()` is correct. The method signature builder.setBolt(String id, IBasicBolt bolt, Number parallelism_hint) should accept the parameters that you are passing as long as the JDK version set is 1.5 or above.

Starting from the Java version 1.5 [Autoboxing feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), the imported .class or compiled class should resolve the references from primitive int to `java.lang.Integer` to `java.lang.Number` as `java.lang.Number` is super class.

The main issue could be the JDK version 1.4 or less set in your project or workspace settings. Changing the JDK version to 1.5 or above should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm</artifactId>
<version>0.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```